# Create multiple objects in class

Tags: c++

I have a class which I use to make linked lists. In the main I want to create more than one lists. I mean without overwriting the previous one. How can I do this without having to give a new name to create an object of the class. If for example I had to do 1000 lists I couldn't give 1000 different names to them. I tried using an array of objects but I don't seem to get it to work.

EDIT:Sorry for the inconvenience but I'm not allowed to use vector.
  here's some code:

```
 list **root;
root=new list*[M];
for (int i=0;i<M;i++)
{
    root[i]=NULL;
    root[i]=new list();

}
```

this is in main an then i use this

```
 (*root[pos]).addnode(b,a);
```

No matter what pos I use it all go into the same list.

Comment: Well, get it to work or post what failed, because an array is the way to go.

Comment: If you couldn't create an array of your linked lists, your linked list has bugs. The way forward is to find those bugs and fix them. Post some code (as little as possible) that doesn't work with an array.

Comment: @molbdnilo I added some code

Answer (score 0):

If you created some linked list class `LinkedList` you could create a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of your lists. Then you can iterate over them and do whatever you'd like.

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<LinkedList> lists(1000);
    for (auto& list : lists)
    {
        // do something with each list
    }
}
```

If you know exactly how many `LinkedList` objects you want to make, and that value is fixed, you could also use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

```
#include <array>
int main()
{
    std::array<LinkedList, 1000> lists;
    for (auto& list : lists)
    {
        // do something with each list
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest using the homogeneous `for (auto&& list : lists)`.

Comment: Why? Iterating over references to each item in the `vector` will work just fine.

Comment: Just a stylistic choice, because `auto&&` will always work. `auto&` can break, e.g with `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: I am not allowed to use vector @CoryKramer

Answer (score 0):

You can a vector just to store your linked lists or you can use a map if you want to access them using a key.

```
// Here you can use a string to find a specific list
std::map<std::string, LinkedList> listMap;
// Then you can add and access list using the [] operator
listMap["Key"];

// Here you have to use an iterator to access the lists
std::vector<LinkedList> listVector(numberOfListsYouPlanToHave);
```